# Web pages opened from Instagram won't play html5 video on Android

Tags: android, html, angular, video, instagram

In iOS everything is working perfectly so I will just focus on Android instead. If I try to open the page in Chrome or Samsung Internet the video autoplays and is all great. Now if I try to open the page from Instagram (promotions and stuff) or using mobile DuckDuckGo browser, a black box with a triangle in the middle (where the video was supposed to play) appears and it won't play even if clicked.
Is there anything I am missing? Once again, this only happens on Android. Thanks!

```
<div #video class="banner-video div-wrapper">
  <video autoplay onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" loop 
  playsinline>
    <source [src]="mediaHost + '/bannervideo.mp4'" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you create the video on an apple device? If yes, then not all browsers will play it(.MOV extension file).

Comment: Well my college made it using an app on his iPhone but it outputs .mp4 videos which are intended for Instagram use. This video is only 1.4 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that Instagram on android uses a lightened up version of the builtin browser. Here's the code that finally made it run in every single device I have tested:

```
<div #video class="banner-video div-wrapper">
  <video loop muted autoplay playsinline oncanplay="this.play()" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" [poster]="mediaHost + '/package.png'">
    <source [src]="mediaHost + '/bannervideo.mp4'" type="video/mp4">
    <p>Your Browser Does Not Support This Autoplay Video Feature</p>
  </video>
</div>
```